# dummify variables in data table with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data table with lots of numeric variables. I would like to transform this table in a way that the variables are replaced by dummies (1 if the variable is larger than zero).

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(replicate(5,sample(0:3,5,replace=TRUE)))
DT
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1:  3  3  0  3  2
2:  0  2  3  0  1
3:  2  1  3  2  0
4:  3  1  1  1  3
5:  0  2  0  2  3
```

I would like to transform this table to something like this:

```r
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1:  1  1  0  1  1
2:  0  1  1  0  1
3:  1  1  1  1  0
4:  1  1  1  1  1
5:  0  1  0  1  1
```

Is there a way I can achieve this with `dplyr`? I tried `mutate_each` but could not figure out how I can use my own function within mutate. The solution below does not work.

```r
DT <- DT %>%
  mutate_each(funs(function(x) {as.numeric(x>0)}))
```

Comment: If you already using  `data.table`, why are you trying to solve it using `dplyr`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I use `fread` from `data.table` but otherwise find the syntax of `dplyr` more intuitive for the simple tasks I usually perform.

Comment: What's wrong with `df[df>0]<-1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could simply do "double negation" (`!!`) and add `0` to convert to a binary matrix.  The first negation (`!DT`) gives `TRUE` for all `0` values, leaving other values `FALSE`.  Negate again to change the `FALSE` to `TRUE` and add `0` which coerces the logical matrix to binary matrix.

```
(!!DT) + 0L
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
tbl_df(DT) %>% mutate_each(funs((!!.) + 0L))
```

Or just use `data.table` (which you already using) an update your columns by reference

```
DT[, names(DT) := lapply(.SD, function(x) (!!x) + 0L)]
```

Or an option using `set` from `data.table` that updates by reference.  So, it will be efficient.

```
 for(j in seq_len(ncol(DT))){
   set(DT, i=NULL, j=j, value=(!!DT[[j]])+0L)
  }
```

Comment: Oh please do explain what's going on here. Isn't `!!` a double negative?

Comment: Or `DT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) (!!x) + 0L)]`

Comment: @Laurik Yes it is a double negative.  Or you can just use  `tbl_df(DT) %>% mutate_each(funs((.>0)+0L))`.  The first `!` converts to TRUE/FALSE for `0/other values`, `!` again for `FALSE/TRUE`

Comment: Btw, I think you should also add your `(!!DT)+0L` as well, as I guess it would be the most efficient one

Comment: Cool. So the `+0L` is like a good/best way to do as.integer() that also works with non-vectors? Learn something new every day :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg When I used `DT` directly, and assign the result to an object `res`.  The output gets printed only after typing `res` two times.  Do you have the same problem?

Comment: @akrun not sure what you mean? What were you trying to assign exactly? The `dplyr` solution?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I don't know if `(!!DT)+0L` is that efficient for big datasets as it converts to a big logical matrix

Comment: @DavidArenburg Suppose `res <- DT %>% mutate_each(funs(as.numeric(.>0)))` Then I have to type `res` twice to get it printed on the console

Comment: Maybe, didn't test it. The `data.table` assignment by reference would be preferable. Still breaking my head why on earth OP was trying to solve this using `dplyr`

Comment: Yeah, I have it too. Not sure if bug in `dplyr` or `data.table`. I'll fill an issue.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for filing it.  I noticed this behavior earlier too using just `data.table`

Comment: It seems like it doesn't happen with `data.table` though in this example

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Thanks, I will remove the extra object